# How do I sample from the posterior distribution with gamma likelihood with unknown alpha and beta?

Tags: bayesian, sampling, posterior, gamma-distribution

I realize that [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) provides the proportional form of the conjugate prior to the gamma distribution with unknown $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters, as well as the posterior values of $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$, which are the hyperparameters of the gamma likelihood (see the last distribution in the table under "Continuous distributions"). I do not, however, know how in practice to sample from the conjugate prior to the Gamma with unknown $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters. Could I get some pointers?

Comment: "In practice" you would be sampling from the posterior, which is a Gamma. Are you asking how to sample a Gamma variate?

Comment: As far as I understand, the conjugate prior to a Gamma distribution with unknown alpha and beta is NOT a Gamma distribution (although the conjugate prior to a Gamma distribution with unknown alpha but known beta is). I am asking how to sample from the non-standard conjugate prior to the Gamma distribution with unknown alpha and beta, which is available on the Wikipedia page I linked to under "Continuous distributions", and it is the last distribution in the table.

Comment: @Brash have you tried rejection sampling or importance sampling or some sort of MCMC method like Metropolis-Hastings?